How does the steering wheel return to the centre after turning (and letting go)? What forces are causing the self centreing torque?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLbs8kBXgrw
This is a very interesting phenomenon to me as it is purely physical and not a result of hydraulics or whatever.
I watched this video (please watch it for context as I am following the same scenario). Despite the nice animations I am still confused.
I tried to visualise and imagine it, then I sketched it, but I still don't understand what forces are at play to cause the self centering torque, that causes the wheel to go from tilted to straight.
Here is my interpretation. The scenario is a left turn. First I drew the scenario:

blue dotted line is the steering axis to which the wheel pivots, caused by the result of a positive caster angle
The red dash is where the tyre contacts the road. T
the purple arrow is the centripetal force pointing inward


Then I drew a top down view of above diagram (excuse the poor diagram):
-blue line is the steering axis, dotted line is how it orients itself after centering.
-purple arrow is the centripetal force that causes an inwards torque at the pivot
-red arrow is the self centering torque

(P.S. just realised that the pivot is actually "imaginary", all the forces and torques acting are through the contact point of the tyre on road. I don't think that invalidates the logic but yes the diagram of torques acting is certainly not right)
I don't see what force is acting in the right/opposite direction to the centripetal force, therefore I don't understand how the self centering torque will rotate the wheel right. Obviously it must rotate right to straighten the wheel and centre. However the only force in the video mentioned is the centripetal force, which is inward, and causes a leftward torque at the pivot towards the centre of the turn.
is it friction? Can someone give me a diagram of the moment arm and the forces?
Thanks

The simplest instance of using caster angle to give a wheel a tendency to return to a particular orientation is with the type of caster wheel that a shopping cart has, but with the pivot axis at a (slight) angle.

Vertical versus angled
If the pivot axis of the caster wheel of the shopping cart is vertical then there is no preferred orientation.
But with the pivot axis (slightly) angled there is one orientation for which the center of mass of the cart is the lowest. So: if you push the cart such that the caster wheel swivels the center of mass of the cart is raised. As you roll that cart along the cart will tend to return to that lower height of the center of mass, making the caster wheel return to the orientation with lowest center of mass.
In the case of car suspension the pivot axis is close to the wheel axis (rather than significantly offset such as in the case of a shopping cart caster wheel), making the effect more subtle. For a car the car suspension setup is sufficient; the sheer weight of the car makes the orienting effect more prounounced.

Stability of steering is complicated and not completely understood.
You might watch this video from MinutePhysics - How Do Bikes Stay Up?. Or this from Veritasium - Most People Don't Know How Bikes Work.  These are about bicycles. A little different from cars, but some of the same ideas apply. These videos also show how castor helps steer. Perhaps these explanations will be a little clearer the video you linked.
There is one big difference between cars and bicycles/motorcycles. For a bicycle, you must lean while turning to stay upright. Cars lean a little outward as they turn. Suspensions are designed to limit the tilt. Cars stay upright because they have 4 wheels. So car stability is not about positioning the wheels directly under the rider. Other things matter. See How Steering Geometry Maximises Performance and Control for a brief list. Note that Kingpin angle also matters.

The video that the OP linked to is exclusively about car suspension. The subjects of bicycles and motorcycles are absent in that video. In the question there is no mention of bicycles or motorcycles. That said: the word 'car' is also absent in (the current version of) the question, so there is a lack of context. And yes, the OP does not give any description of the content of the video; the OP is totally relying on people checking out the video.

Yes it is about car suspension. Specifically about how castor affects car suspension. I didn't think it was especially clear, so I linked some bicycle videos about the same thing. There are differences. I don't have much specific to car suspensions, so this isn't a very complete answer. Perhaps he will get some use out of it anyway. +1 to yours.
